# What is the name of this plant with many purple blooms with orange inner parts?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I have photographed the following plant in Pittsburgh, PA. It has many blooms and every bloom is very small (about 5mm diameter), purple on the outer and orange in the inner. You can see it here:

[image]

What is the name of that plant?

Comment: Here is a listing of a bunch of different butterfly bushes in all their glory! http://www.naturehills.com/bushes-and-shrubs/butterfly-bushes
http://www.naturehills.com/about-garden-plants/about-butterfly-bush

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks pretty much like [Buddleja davidii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddleja_davidii) to me. They are available in a range of different colors, see this image from the Wikipedia:

[image]